# Using parcelable and intent in the same activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, parcelable

I use 2 intent in same activity.One of them for take input Firstname,Lastname and Id.Other intent for send data to another activity.
But when I use intents like that code didn't work. 
Can I use intents like that

```
intent.putExtra("lastName", intent2.getString("lastName"));
```

Search Activity

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SearchActivity.class);
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putString("firstName", firstName);
b.putString("lastName", lastName);
b.putString("id", id);
b.putParcelable("LoginPartClass",lp2);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

Search Activity code

```
        final Bundle intent2 = getIntent().getExtras();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AnotherActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("keywords", keywords);
        if(intent2!=null) {
           final String Firstname=intent2.getString("firstName");
           intent.putExtra("firstName", Firstname);  }
           intent.putExtra("lastName", intent2.getString("lastName"));
           intent.putExtra("id", intent2.getString("id"));
        }
        startActivity(intent);
```

Parceable Class

```
public class LoginPart implements Parcelable{

private Token requestoken;
private OAuthService s;
private String authURL;


public LoginPart(Token Token, OAuthService S, String AuthURL) {
    requestoken = Token;
    s = S;
    authURL = AuthURL;
}

public LoginPart( ) {

}


public Token getRequestoken() {
    return requestoken;
}

public void setRequestoken(Token requestoken) {
    this.requestoken = requestoken;
}

public OAuthService getS() {
    return s;
}

public Parcelable getSParcelable() {
    return (Parcelable) s;
}
public void setS(OAuthService s) {
    this.s = s;
}

public String getAuthURL() {
    return authURL;
}

public void setAuthURL(String authURL) {
    this.authURL = authURL;
}

public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dest.writeValue(requestoken);
    dest.writeValue(s);
    dest.writeValue(authURL);

}

 }
```

Problem is related to Parcable class.When I use parceable class make crash.How can I solve that?

Comment: `getIntent().getExtras();` contains parameters sent by the previous activity.

Comment: You should reconsider how you name your variables. `intent2` is not an `Intent` but a `Bundle` so its a little confusing, IMHO. What is the problem you are having? If its crashing then post your logcat. You can add data from a `Bundle` to another `Intent` if that was the question.

Comment: I edited question.Because problem is related parceable class.If I remove intent it works succesfully.So problem is related to parceable class

Answer (score 0):

in your first activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("id", 1);
    b.putString("firstName", "this is my first name");
    b.putString("lastName", "this is my last name");
    intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(intent);
```

in second activity:

```
Bundle b =getIntent().getExtras();



    String name  =b.getString("firstName");
    String lastname  =b.getString("lastName");
```

Comment: I edited question.Because problem is related parceable class.If I remove intent it works succesfully.So problem is related to parceable class

Comment: you have to use the putExtra insted of putParcelable. something like this  Parcelableobject parcelableobj = new Parcelableobject();
 
    //Store Parcelable object in Intent
    intent.putExtra("myparcableobject", parcelableobj);

Comment: refer this Example http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/android-sending-object-from-one-activity-to-another-using-parcelable/

Comment: When I convert to putParceable , IDE doesn't allow.

Comment: use putExtra : Intent intent.putExtra("myparcableobject", parcelableobj);

Answer (score 0):

chane your LoginPart class like this...

```
public class LoginPart implements Parcelable {
    private Token requestoken;
    private OAuthService s;
    private String authURL;


    public LoginPart(Token Token, OAuthService S, String AuthURL) {
        requestoken = Token;
        s = S;
        authURL = AuthURL;
    }

    public LoginPart( ) {

    }

    public LoginPart(Parcel parcel) {
        requestoken = parcel.readValue(getClassLoader());
        s = parcel.readValue(getClassLoader());
        authURL = parcel.readValue(getClassLoader());
    }


    public Token getRequestoken() {
        return requestoken;
    }

    public void setRequestoken(Token requestoken) {
        this.requestoken = requestoken;
    }

    public OAuthService getS() {
        return s;
    }

    public Parcelable getSParcelable() {
        return (Parcelable) s;
    }
    public void setS(OAuthService s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public String getAuthURL() {
        return authURL;
    }

    public void setAuthURL(String authURL) {
        this.authURL = authURL;
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dest.writeValue(requestoken);
        dest.writeValue(s);
        dest.writeValue(authURL);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<LoginPart> CREATOR = new Creator<SecondActivity.LoginPart>() {

        @Override
        public LoginPart[] newArray(int size) {
            return new LoginPart[size];
        }

        @Override
        public LoginPart createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new LoginPart(source);
        }
    };
}
```

for this to work, your Token class and OAuthService class should implement Parcelable

Comment: requestoken = parcel.readValue(getClassLoader()); something wrong this part.IDE doesnt allow and underlines getClassLoader()

Comment: otherwise you can use *getClass().getClassLoader()*